# ECMAScript 6 Map & Set - Safe to delete during iteration?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, set, iteration, ecmascript-6

As the title suggests, is it safe to iterate over the new Set & Map types and delete entries during the iteration ?

In Java, for instance, this would cause ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

I was not able to find anything about this issue in the spec. So I guess it's allowed ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [MapIterator object's `next()` section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%mapiteratorprototype%.next),

> 9. Let *entries* be the List that is the value of the [[MapData]] internal slot of m.
> 10. Repeat while *index* is less than the total number of elements of entries. **The number of elements must be redetermined each time this method is evaluated.**

...
...

> 11. Set the [[Map]] internal slot of O to **undefined**.
> 12. Return *CreateIterResultObject(**undefined**, **true**)*.

Similarly from [SetIterator object's `next()` section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%setiteratorprototype%.next),

> 9. Let *entries* be the List that is the value of the [[SetData]] internal slot of s.
> 10. Repeat while *index* is less than the total number of elements of entries. **The number of elements must be redetermined each time this method is evaluated.**

...
...

> 11. Set the [[IteratedSet]] internal slot of O to **undefined**.
> 12. Return *CreateIterResultObject(**undefined**, **true**)*.

Since the values are re-evaluated everytime `next()` is called, if the current pointer (*index*) is greater than the length of the entries, then it doesn't throw an error, instead returns `undefined`.

---

But, generally, avoid modifying the containers while iterating the same.

Comment: Notice though that the *number of entries* doesn't decrease. They just get set to `empty`. So it basically just says that new elements do have to get iterated.